# Brightness settings are not saved permanently in Debian 7

Tags: brightness

Am using Toshiba satellite L750 series laptop and using Debian 7 as  operating system. I managed to control brightness after installing Nvida driver's but the brightness settings are not saved permanently . Each time after a reboot I had to decrease brightness. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: was this happening with out the nvidia software beforehand?

Comment: Before that brightness couldn't be changed.There will be maximum brightness all the time. The same issue was there when I used Debian derivatives like ubuntu & mint.